# Pylons logging for 500 after failed shell call in view

Tags: shell, perl, debugging, logging, pylons

I am new to pylons and I want a web page to request and process JSON that is emitted by a perl script on the server.  This isn't working as below but I can find no logs for either errors or requests for pserve.  I have googled and read the logging doco for pylons.  If you can see what's wrong below also that would be great, but I suspect the shell call is broken.  I just a way to debug it.

I have set up the web page to use AJAX to call a view:

### views.py called via pserve on windows 7

```
import os

from pyramid.view import view_config
from subprocess import check_output
@view_config(route_name='overlay_event', renderer='json')
def event_view(request):
    return {'new_overlay': subprocess.check_output(['perl', 'hello_ajax/static/overlay_event.pl', 'ping']),
            'html_overlay': subprocess.check_output(['perl', 'hello_ajax/static/overlay_event.pl', 'json'])
            }
```

### client page ajax (running in Chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
setInterval(
     function () {jQuery.ajax({
                    url     : 'overlay_event',
                    cache   : false,
                    type    : 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){ if(new_overlay != 0) 
                                                { //lots more code......
```

This gets me a 500 according to the Chrome console.  However, I can find no server side logs for pserve and nothing appears on server console.
The Perl script returns JSON to stdout.  I want the JSON captured by the view and sent back in the POST request so it can be eval'd in the client.

### development.ini is below - it is unchanged except for logging set to DEBUG not INFO by me.

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.8-branch/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:hello_ajax

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar

# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
# debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
listen = 127.0.0.1:6543 [::1]:6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.8-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, hello_ajax

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console

[logger_hello_ajax]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = hello_ajax

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Any help to turn on logging to work out what is broken would be great.

Comment: I think you mean Pyramid. Pylons the web framework is in maintenance mode, and Pylons Project is a collection of projects, including Pyramid. See https://pylonsproject.org/about-pylons-project.html If so, then please update your question, tags, and title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's Pyramid.  At any rate, I found some answers.  For those who may benefit from this:

google handler_filelog for development.ini.  This makes a log file. Turn logging up from INFO to DEBUG.  I still don't know why before this I got 500s on the browser console and not a squeak from pserve console.

Add shell=True in the subprocess call so perl gets environment vars and cwd.  Apparently this is a security risk.

Also check cwd for target script with 'perl' '-MCwd -e' 'print cwd;' This will confirm the perl shell call is happening in the file system where you think it is.

Returned JSON from perl shell call is made into an object via newobject=JSON.parse  this may need to be run twice if the JSON is also marked up by the shell.

I developed for perl and Apache before web2.  Ideally, I'd be able to keep using Perl and it would somehow play with pserve for server resources and state but I can't find anything suggesting this is on the cards.  This would allow me to more gently transition and update.